# Maintaining a layout relationship across the visual tree

Tags: wpf, layout

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <GroupBox Header="Chart Area" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.RowSpan="6"/>

    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Title:</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="10,0,10,0"></TextBox>

    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">X</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Y</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Width</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Height</Label>

    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Position:</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Width="60"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Width="60"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Width="60"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3" Width="60"></TextBox>

    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Colour:</Label>
    <Rectangle Margin="10,2,10,2" Fill="LightGreen" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" />


    <GroupBox Header="Plot Area" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Imagine this was a particularly long title:</Label>
    <Rectangle Margin="10,2,10,2" Fill="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="8" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />

</Grid>
```

[image]

In the example above I've "hacked"/cheated on the layout. The controls which appear to be under the visual tree for the GroupBox are not. I've done this so the width of all the labels are the same and they align nicely.

This feels like naughty/bad way of doing things (although it is quite effective).

I could have done this with hard-coded widths but that wouldn't work well with labels that vary in length.

I guess I could bind the widths somehow.

Can anyone suggest alternative/better solutions please?

Thanks David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF has a mechanism for this built in via the attached property `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope='True'` which can be added to a container controller higher up the visual tree.

so you could do this:-

```
<StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    ... add controls

    <GroupBox>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ColA"/>
          <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ColB"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      .... add controls

      </Grid>
    </GroupBox>

    <GroupBox>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ColA"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      .... add controls

      </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
```

The columns with the same text names (e.g. "ColA") in the two separate Grid sections will now synchronise widths.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a grid inside your groupbox and you code will be better

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Header="Chart Area">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Title:</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"  Margin="2"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ></TextBox>

            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">X</Label>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Y</Label>
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Width</Label>
            <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Height</Label>

            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Position:</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="2"  Width="60"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="2"  Width="60"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="2"  Width="60"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="2"  Width="60"></TextBox>

            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Colour:</Label>
            <Rectangle Margin="2" Fill="LightGreen" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Plot Area" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.4*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.6*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Imagine this was a particularly long title:</Label>
            <Rectangle Margin="10,2,10,2" Fill="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
        </Grid>

    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```